# iOS AFNetworking - ASP.NET Web API .ASPXAUTH storage and deletion

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, afnetworking, sbjson, .aspxauth

I'm using the AFNetworking Framework for iOS.  I've subclassed AFHttpClient and are using it as a singleton, i.e. `[TestAFClient sharedClient]`

I'm consuming an ASP.NET Web Service API that requires the use of the .ASPXAUTH cookie.  First I have to authenticate, receive the .ASPXAUTH cookie in response, and then must pass this cookie with each subsequent request.

After a few tests, it appears that, because I'm using a singleton AFHTTPClient, the .ASPXAuth cookie persists and, thus, no explicit storage of the cookie is required.

However, as part of my App, I need to "logout" at some point.

What is the most efficient way to clear this cookie, in order to logout?  Set the singleton to `nil` and re-initialize it? Do something like `setValue:forKey:`?

Additionally, is it better that I explicitly store the .ASPXAUTH cookie? And does this expire or automatically renew if necessary?

Thanks,

Robby

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cookies are actually handled by the underlying URL-loading system, similar to the way cacheing is handled automatically by `NSURLCache`. For `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`, you'll want to find the cookie at your `baseURL`, and then delete it. You can explicitly set or modify an existing cookie in the same way.